# VBA code to make an ODBC connection to HIVE?

Tags: vba

I am looking for the VBA code which would make the ODBC connection to hive, which could directly pull up the table into the excel sheet.
I have done this manually by going to data tab, select the new ODBC connection and all, but looking to do this automated way by VBA code.

Comment: Start [recording a macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code) and repeat your actions.

Comment: I tried that, but its not working.

Comment: post the recorded macro code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question.  I don't have access to hive right now, but it seem like this should work.

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Step 3:

[image]

Start your Macro recorder before you click through the steps and you should have all the code you need to automate this process.

See the link below for more details.

https://blog.learningtree.com/how-to-use-power-query-to-import-hadoop-data-into-excel/